# Beginner R: How do I create a comparative boxplot using two transposed datasets?

Tags: r, boxplot, transpose, read.table

Disclaimer: I am VERY new to R

In summary, I have two datasets ("fabricH.txt" and "fabricP.txt") that are comparing the same variable (extensibility) for two different populations (fabrics). All I need is to make a single graph with one boxplot for each. The problem is that the datasets are transposed (i.e. 1 row with n number of columns). This is on purpose, as we are supposed to figure it out by using code rather than manually changing the dataset files.

## The issue:

- when I use the t() function, the data is read transposed, but the boxplot() function will not let me add two data tables, only one at a time.

The assignment instructions are as follows:

"The data on extensibility (100%)
at 100 gm/cm for both high-quality fabric (H) and poor -quality fabric (P) specimens is given in fabricH.txt and fabricP.txt"

"Construct a comparative boxplot. Does it suggest that there is a difference between true average extensibility for high-quality fabric specimens and that for poor-quality specimens?"

The data are:
fabricH.txt:

```
1.2 .9 .7 1.0 1.7 1.7 1.1 .9 1.7 1.9 1.3 2.1 1.6 1.8 1.4 1.3 1.9 1.6 .8 2.0 1.7 1.6 2.3 2.0
```

fabricP.txt:

```
1.6 1.5 1.1 2.1 1.5 1.3 1.0 2.6
```

reading the .txt files into a transposed matrix:

```
fabricH<-t(read.table("fabricH.txt",header=F))  
fabricP<-t(read.table("fabricP.txt",header=F))
```

then simply try to plot into a single plot for both datasets:

```
boxplot(fabricH, fabricP)
```

I get the error:

> "Error in dimnames(x)[[1 + use.cols]] : no such index at level 2 In
> addition: Warning message: In if (use.cols) { :   the condition has
> length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

~ I am assuming this is connected to the matrices being of [1:N, 1] size. But don't know how I would change my matrices to make it work.

~ I also was not able to find a solution for this level of coding (very basic).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of handling this problem is to get all of your data into one data frame with two columns.  One column for the values and the second column for the source/name.  Once there you can plot the value vs name.

```
#sample data
fabricH<-c(1.2, .9, .7, 1.0, 1.7, 1.7, 1.1, .9, 1.7, 1.9, 1.3, 2.1, 1.6, 1.8, 1.4, 1.3, 1.9, 1.6, .8, 2.0, 1.7, 1.6, 2.3, 2.0)
fabricP<-c(1.6, 1.5, 1.1, 2.1, 1.5, 1.3, 1.0, 2.6)

#with the sample data...
#make a data frame with two columns named: "name" and "value"
fabricH_df<-data.frame(name="fabricH", value=fabricH)
fabricP_df<-data.frame(name="fabricP", value=fabricP)

#combine separate data frames into one large dataframe
combined<-rbind(fabricH_df, fabricP_df)

#plot the values grouped by "name"
boxplot(value ~ name, data=combined)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This is very useful :)

Comment: @VeroRodriguez-j, Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers